# Masonry layout not filling space when filtered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry, masonry

I made a masonry layout that is filtered on click.

For some reason, when some of the buttons are selected, the masonry layout floats left and stacks all items above eachother instead of filling the container. I'm not sure why this is happening, on isotope it is fine with:

```
$grid.isotope({ layoutMode: 'masonry' })
```

Masonry doesn't seem to have this layoutMode built in and I cannot use Isotope for this project.

I'm not sure where I am going wrong, here is a codepen: 
http://codepen.io/H0BB5/pen/ORVBzm

the layout is perfect for 'view all' and 'congratulations' but not for 'thank you'.

*Edit*: 
I noticed that the cause of 'congratulations' filling the space is because the first two grid-item's in the html have the 'congratulations' class. This must somehow be forcing the layout to fill horizontally rather than vertically. Still haven't found a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring out the problem. 
If anyone else has the same issue, I found my solution by reading the documentation further.

```
<div class="grid">
  <!-- .grid-sizer empty element, only used for element sizing -->
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
  ...
</div>

/* fluid 5 columns */
.grid-sizer,
.grid-item { width: 20%; }
/* 2 columns wide */
.grid-item--width2 { width: 40%; }
// use outer width of grid-sizer for columnWidth
columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
itemSelector: '.grid-item',
percentPosition: true
```

now working pen: http://codepen.io/H0BB5/pen/ORVBzm